# Range A = range A^tA

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m\geq n$. ¿Is it true that **rank** $A$ is equal to **rank** $A^tA$?.  How show this?

Thanks!

Comment: What you can prove is that $\text{range }A^\top=\text{range }A^\top A$.

Comment: Thanks! It is true, I duplicated the question. I am sorry, and thanks for the link with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample $$A={1\choose0}\quad A^TA=(1)$$

Actually, if $m\neq n$, then range of $A$ is subspace of $\mathbb R^m$ while range of $A^TA$ is subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: sorry, it was rank, not range.

Comment: @user106306 Well, I think you found the answer now.

Comment: yes, thanks for your help and time. (Although, it is always good to see an alternative proof).