# If $A, B \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $AA^{T} = BB^{T}$, then $\mathrm{Im} A = \mathrm{Im} B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw this property of gaussian vector : If $X$ is a random vector of normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, then $X$ takes values a.s. in $\{\mu + x \mid x \in \mathrm{Im}\Sigma^{1/2} \}$.

To prove this, we can use the fact that $X \sim \mu + \Sigma^{1/2}Z$ where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_{n})$.

I think this propery suggest (implies) that if $A, B \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $AA^{T} = BB^{T}$, then $\mathrm{Im} A = \mathrm{Im} B$.

I'm not sure if this is correct and how to prove this directly from linear algebra?

Comment: Isn't this just [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946579/how-to-prove-the-range-of-aat-is-the-same-as-range-of-a)? So $im(A)=im(AA^T)=im(BB^T)=im(B)$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes. This anwser my question, thank you.